# What's the etymology of the name of the Schengen village?

Tags: europe, language, toponymy

The Luxembourg village of [Schengen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen,_Luxembourg) is noted for being the site where European leaders signed the historic [Schengen Agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Agreement). The village is named for its [1390 castle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Castle).

Where does the name "Schengen" originally come from? Does *"Schengen"* means anything in German or Luxembourgish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this: [http://www.etymologie.info/~e/l_/lu-**gr**.html](http://www.etymologie.info/~e/l_/lu-__gr__.html)

Der Name des Ortes "Schengen" (im Großherzogtum Luxemburg (Kanton Remich), der Namensgeberin für das "Schengener Abkommen", engl. "Schengen Treaty", "Schengen Agreement", 1985) soll keltischen Ursprungs sein und auf kelt. "scen" = dt. "Schilfwasser" zurück gehen. Im Jahr 877 erscheint der Name des Ortes erstmals als "Sceidingas".

In brief: It is considered to come from a Celtic word for "reed water".